# HTML link not working. Output "Your connection is not private"

Tags: jquery, html, css, hosting

I am currently trying to set up links towards my portfolio section of my website.
Whenever I try to click on the links and access any item of my portfolio section I receive this output: Your connection is not private. I also get this error when I view the advanced details in Firefox:

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I've searched around old stack posts and some questions in the Firefox support forum but the solutions don't currently help me. The results are the same when I try to access the items on the website from a different computer.

HTML Code:

```
 <section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" id ="port">
                    <h2 class="section-heading" id="portfolio-title">Portfolio</h2>
                    <p>Here you can observe some of my accomplished projects and fork me on GitHub. ;) </p>
                </div>
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="https://www.wickeddevs.net/2" class="portfolio-box">
                        <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" id="box-one">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                    Band Website
                                </div>
                                <div class="project-name">
                                    Lelahell Personal Website
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6" >
                    <a href="www.wickeddevs.net/faded" class="portfolio-box">
                        <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" id ="box-two">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                    Barbershop Website
                                </div>
                                <div class="project-name">
                                   FADED
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="https://www.wickeddevs.net/1" class="portfolio-box">
                        <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" id ="box-three">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                    Data Entry Start up
                                </div>
                                <div class="project-name">
                                    Go Progression
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ZombieChowder11" class="portfolio-box">
                        <img src="img/portfolio/4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" id="box-four">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                    Github
                                </div>
                                <div class="project-name">
                                    My other backend web projects<br>
                                    can be found on my github account.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I think it might be something I should try and fix from my C-panel but I'm quite unsure about that. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you use `https://` ?

Comment: Even when I change the links in the html file to not having "https:///", it still yields the same result!

Comment: This error does not relate to html codes but a windows setting on IP causes this. check this video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIkUWjYnhkM

Comment: Did everything in the video, nothing has changed..

Comment: Possibly your router or networks blocks connection to special IP which are listed as unsecure.

Comment: Ok, thanks but that doesn't help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what's the problem. My portfolio items are hosted on the same domain and when I'm trying to access them, I write my website's name twice thus giving the security error. I fixed by simply writing:

```
 <a href="/2" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
```

This only redirects to a folder on my main domain.